# Images of the map $f(z)=\frac{2z-1}{2-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

> What is the image of
>
> - the real line
> - the imaginary line
> - the unit circle
>
> Under the map $f(z)=\frac{2z-1}{2-z}$

Assume $z=x+iy$. Then setting $$w=f(z)=\frac{2(x+iy)-1}{2-iy-x}=\frac{(2x-1+2iy)(2-x+iy)}{(2-x)^2+y^2}$$.

Since the real line has $y=0$ we get the image:

$$w=\frac{(2x-1)(2-x)}{(2-x)^2}$$

Now this is in terms of $x$, when ideally I would have variables $w=u+iv$, does it mean I simply need to call $x=u$?

Similarly for the imaginary line by setting $x=0$ this time.

**What happens for a unit circle?**

Let $|z|=1=e^{it}$ for $t\in [0,2\pi]$. Then the image is $$f(z)=\frac{2e^{it}-1}{2-e^{it}}$$

However, what do these images actually look like? Are they lines, circles etc.? I know that circles map to circles and since $|z|\ne 2$ for the unit circle, it doesn't have a point at infinity $\rightarrow$ it's a circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the image of the real line, you find a result that can be simplified into :

$$w=\frac{2x-1}{2-x}$$

and we know that $x \rightarrow w$ is bijective from $\mathbb{R}-2$ to $\mathbb{R}-\{-2\}$: the real axis minus a single point.

- For the image of the unit circle, let us consider the inverse of $Z=\dfrac{2z-1}{2-z}$ (as advised by @David Quinn) i.e.

$$z=2\dfrac{Z+\dfrac12}{Z+2} \ \ \ (1)$$

Thus, expressing that $z \in C(0,1)$ (unit circle), a consequence of (1) is:

$$ |z|=1 \Leftrightarrow 2\dfrac{|Z+\dfrac12|}{|Z+2|}=1 \Leftrightarrow |Z-(-2)|=2|Z-(-\frac12)|\Leftrightarrow dist(M,A)=2 dist(M,B)$$

(by setting $A(-2,0)$ and $B(-\frac12,0)$, $M$ corresponding to $Z$).

We are now able to apply a classical result: the locus of points $M$ such that $dist(M,A) \ = \ 2 \ dist(M,B)$ with fixed points $A$ and $B$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius) is a circle with center on axis $AB$; its characteristics are rather easy to derive (center in $(-9/4,0)$, radius $5/2$).

Remark: This method can be applied to the image of the unit circle by any (homographic) transformation $Z=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$. One will find always $dist(M,A)=k dist(M,B)$ for some $A$, $B$ and $k$. In some cases, one can find $k=1$ : in such a case, it is no longer a circle, but a straght line.

Comment: Thanks, do you know where I could read about deriving the equation for the circle?

Comment: For the equation of the circle, it suffices to square both sides:$dist(M,A)^2 \ = \ 4 \ dist(M,B)^2$, then write it as$(x+1/2)^2+y^2=4((x+2)^2+y^2)$, then expand... You ask for references;here is a general one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation ; another one with nice figures: www.ams.org/notices/200810/tx081001226p.pdf and a more theoretical one: www.johno.dk/mathematics/moebius.pdf

Answer (score 2):

HINT...write $$w=\frac {2z-1}{2-z}$$ and rearrange to make $z$ the subject.

Put $w=u+iv$ and apply the conditions on $z$ to obtain cartesian equations in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: I found that $z=(2w+1)/(w+2)$ and also $x=(2u+1)/(2+u)$ which would imply that the image is also a full real line. What would a circle map to? Also a circle?